# How to disable typographic ligature when using font hinting in xfce

Tags: fonts, xfce4

I use xfce-4. When enabling font hinting, typographic ligatures are automatically made.
The font looks really better, but typographic ligature is not good. How to disable typographic ligatures with font hinting?

This is how it looks with font hinting and without:

[image: with font hinting]
[image: without font hinting]
[image: font hinting + solution #1]

Please pay attention on the "ti" in "questions". The font is calibri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will fix Calibri by disabling the use of the embedded bitmaps via fontconfig:

```
$ cd /etc/fonts/
$ cat conf.avail/75-fix-calibri.conf
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<!-- Use embedded bitmaps in fonts like Calibri? -->
        <match target="font" >
                <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
                        <bool>false</bool>
                </edit>
        </match>
</fontconfig>
$ ln -s conf.avail/75-fix-calibri.conf conf.d/75-fix-calibri.conf
$ ls -l conf.d/75-fix-calibri.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 21. Nov 10:19 conf.d/75-fix-calibri.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/75-fix-calibri.conf
```

You don't actually need to restart X, for this to go into effect as the applications that use freetype2 and indirectly fontconfig only need to be restarted.

**Note that restarting X closes all open windows.** I tend to restart X with Alt-Control-Backspace. But `pkill X` also works.

Source: [bbs.archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=136771)
Tested by OP. Works. See image #3 on initial post.